# Adding calculated columns and then just new data to a Pandas dataframe iteratively (python 3.7.1)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, merge

I have one initial dataframe df1:

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [2, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [3, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [4, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [5, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

        a   b   c   d   e
    0   1   B   C   D   E
    1   2   B   C   D   E
    2   3   B   C   D   E
    3   4   B   C   D   E
    4   5   B   C   D   E
```

Then I compute some new parameters based on df1 column values, create a new df2 and merge with df1 on column name "a".

```
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 'F', 'G'], [2, 'F', 'G']]), columns=['a', 'f', 'g'])

        a   f   g
    0   1   F   G
    1   2   F   G
```

```
    df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='left', left_on=['a'], right_on = ['a'])

        a   b   c   d   e   f   g
    0   1   B   C   D   E   F   G
    1   2   B   C   D   E   F   G
    2   3   B   C   D   E   NaN NaN
    3   4   B   C   D   E   NaN NaN
    4   5   B   C   D   E   NaN NaN
```

This works perfectly fine, but in another loop event, I create a df3 with same columns as df2 but merge in this case does not work, it doesn't take into account that the same columns are already in df1.

**IMPORTANT REMARK**: This is for illustration purpose only, there are thousands of new dataframes to be added, one per loop step.

```
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[3, 'F', 'G']]), columns=['a', 'f', 'g'])

        a   f   g
    0   3   F   G
```

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df3,  how='left', left_on=['a'], right_on = ['a'])

        a   b   c   d   e   f_x g_x f_y g_y
    0   1   B   C   D   E   F   G   NaN NaN
    1   2   B   C   D   E   F   G   NaN NaN
    2   3   B   C   D   E   NaN NaN F   G
    3   4   B   C   D   E   NaN NaN NaN NaN
    4   5   B   C   D   E   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

I just one to fill missing gaps using the already existing columns. This approach creates new columns `(f_x, g_x, f_y, g_y)`.

Append and contact also does not work as they repeats information (repeated rows on "a").

Any advice on how to solve this? **Final result** after merging `df1` with `df2`, and after with `df3` should be:

```
        a   b   c   d   e   f   g
    0   1   B   C   D   E   F   G
    1   2   B   C   D   E   F   G
    2   3   B   C   D   E   F   G
    3   4   B   C   D   E   NaN NaN
    4   5   B   C   D   E   NaN NaN
```

Eventually all the columns will be filled during the loop, so the first added (df2) will add new columns, and from df3 onwards just new data to fill all NaN. The loop looks like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [2, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [3, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [4, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [5, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
```

```
for num, item in enumerate(df1['a']):
    #compute df[num] (based on values on df1)
    df1 = pd.merge(df1, df[num],  how='left', left_on=['a'], right_on = ['a'])
```

Comment: I see your new remark after the edit. Could you maybe show a piece of your `loop` where you `merge` all these dataframes?

Comment: @Erfan It was something like:
`df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [2, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [3, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [4, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], [5, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']]), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])`

`for num, item in enumerate(df1['a'].values):
    #compute df[num]
    df1 = pd.merge(df1, df[num],  how='left', left_on=['a'], right_on = ['a'])`

Comment: Pls include this in your post @juanman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) all small `DataFrame`s and then only once `merge`:

```
df4 = pd.concat([df2, df3])
print (df4)
   a  f  g
0  1  F  G
1  2  F  G
0  3  F  G

df1 = pd.merge(df1, df4,  how='left', on = 'a')
print (df1)
   a  b  c  d  e    f    g
0  1  B  C  D  E    F    G
1  2  B  C  D  E    F    G
2  3  B  C  D  E    F    G
3  4  B  C  D  E  NaN  NaN
4  5  B  C  D  E  NaN  NaN
```

Another possible solution is use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1 = (df1.set_index('a')
         .combine_first(df2.set_index('a'))
         .combine_first(df3.set_index('a')))
print (df1)
   b  c  d  e    f    g
a                      
1  B  C  D  E    F    G
2  B  C  D  E    F    G
3  B  C  D  E    F    G
4  B  C  D  E  NaN  NaN
5  B  C  D  E  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach @jezrael There is one important remark: the new dataframes are generated in a loop, one new at a time. So the first one we merge with the original (df1) is ok, but after we have this issue. We have thousands of dfs to generate so it may not be memory efficient to store all of them and merge them at the end. But I will try.

Comment: @juanman - hmmm, `merge` data in loop should be more memory consumed, but all depends of data. the best test it.

Comment: @juanman - general solution is not easy, I find another one, please check it.

Comment: I've been testing this approach since then, its just taking long due to the amount of math calculations. There are thousands of dataframes to be created, will keep you updated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I confirmed this did the trick! So I created first a list of all the new dataframes, then concatenated them and finally made the merge with the original (df1).

Answer (score 1):

Another way is too use `fillna` then drop the extra columns you dont need anymore:

```
# Fill NaN with the extra columns value
df1.f_x.fillna(df1.f_y, inplace=True)
df1.g_x.fillna(df1.g_y, inplace=True)

   a  b  c  d  e  f_x  g_x  f_y  g_y
0  1  B  C  D  E    F    G  NaN  NaN
1  2  B  C  D  E    F    G  NaN  NaN
2  3  B  C  D  E    F    G    F    G
3  4  B  C  D  E  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  5  B  C  D  E  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

# Slice of the last two columns
df1 = df1.iloc[:, :-2]
# Rename the columns correctly
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.replace('_x', '')
```

**Output**

```
   a  b  c  d  e    f    g
0  1  B  C  D  E    F    G
1  2  B  C  D  E    F    G
2  3  B  C  D  E    F    G
3  4  B  C  D  E  NaN  NaN
4  5  B  C  D  E  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a subset of `df1` in the merge with df3, or alternatively I would keep a copy of the original `df1`.

1. subset:

   ```
   df1.fillna(pd.merge(df1.loc(1)['a':'e'], df3, how='left',
                       left_on=['a'], right_on = ['a']),
              inplace=True)
   ```
2. copy of original data

   ```
   df1_orig = df1           # before merging with df2
   ...
   df1.fillna(pd.merge(df1_orig, df3, how='left',
                       left_on=['a'], right_on = ['a']),
              inplace=True)
   ```